# Tomcat app and global variables stored in database. Manager application to maintain servers and apps

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications

Looking for opinions on setting Tomcat and apps to read database for app and global variables. We developing an app that will let developers and network techs configure web apps and servers. This idea came about because the developers shouldn't care which servers their apps are on and take away the need of making sure web.xml and context.xml are correct for each environment.

We want to have all the servers,environments, and variables held in a database, our manager app will allow developers a easy way to set app variables and global tomcat variables. This app will also allow Jenkins a place to get parms it needs for deploying and building apps.

Any thoughts? Is there a way or shareware to do this already?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As far as my opinion on it, I think it can be a very good idea for certain deployments. I've worked on projects where we did this just as you suggest: have a set of "environmental variables" (I use the quotes because they're not really sysEnv variables, but just data in a database) stored in a database, and then for each deployment environment we'd get the app to read those and deploy configure itself accordingly.

Another way we've done this is by actually using System Environment variables. This works great with Java, as you have a common API for reading those without caring about the Operating System you're on. This is faster to implement if the number of such variables to set is not very big: no need to have a db installed, no need to create/update its schema for the storage of said variables, just make OS-specific scripts that will configure them on each environment. Another advantage is that this way you can create multiple users on the same machine, each with a different set of values for the variables, and just have your application deployed for a certain user in order to have it work for that set of variables (have users like integration, pre-production, etc).

The disadvantage with the latter is when you have a really big number of variables. In this case, setting up some database instances and creating (one common) script for the schema creation/update and insertion of data might be simpler than creating huge, OS-Specific scripts.

Comment: Thanks Shivan. We were planning to use an Initialization servlet for the apps to read the database. Is this how you implemented it? Maybe web service or direct db read?

Comment: Actually we've had more than web-apps using this setup. For the web apps we usually used a context or session listener (so the variables will be re-read with each new deployment, and/or each new user accesing the app respectively). We also had command line tools (like various Java batches) for which we created a common "SettingsReader" library which would read config from env variables, but could also have config files which would override certain variables.